# Nested for loop not functioning properly

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a section of code that is supposed to generate a histogram, given some input, shown here.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& outputStream, aHistogram& h){
outputStream << "Constructing histogram." << endl;
int numberOfBins = h.v.size();
int max = h.getMax();
int longest = h.getLongestLine();
int diceData = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBins; ++i) {
    outputStream << i + h.getNumDice() << ":";
    diceData = h.v.at(i);

    for (int x = 1; x <= (diceData / max) * longest; x++) {
        outputStream << "X";
    }
    outputStream << endl; 
}

return outputStream;}
```

The problem is, it only generates the "max" number of X's for the highest value input, and the loop seems to not work at all for the other values. Here is a screenshot of output.

[image]

I'm not exactly sure what's going wrong here.

Comment: ...which stands for [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried printing out the number `(diceData / max) * longest`? I would guess it's zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
(diceData / max) * longest
```

Using integer math, the division rounds down to 0, and you end up with `0 * longest` when `diceData < max`. Use floating point math to get numbers between 0 and 1, or do the multiplication first.

```
(double) diceData / max * longest
diceData * longest / max
```

Beware of overflow if you use the second approach.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not sure how I let that slip my mind!